# Overriding include functions in php?

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

Is there a way to override include functions (include, include_once, require, require_once, etc) in PHP? I want to be able to do some code before including a file in the script. I'm working on a system that will allow plugins to be installed, but I don't want a plugin opening one or more of the core files and viewing their content. So I would like to be able to block these files when using include functions (especially file_get_contents()) but I obviously can't simply disable these functions.

I have thought about just changing the owner/access rights to these files, but apache needs read/execute rights to these so automatically, we can get their content by using file_get_contents();

Is there a way I can do that? Or am I viewing this the wrong way??

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you're hooped. You will have to trust your plugin developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is worth spending the processing power, you can use `fopen` or `file_get_contents` to read the PHP files as text and search for the forbidden functions, then include or ignore them based on the result.

Comment: It's a great idea. The processing power is not really a concern considering the fact that the system will be on a multiple servers architecture (Dev/Test/Prod). I think I will build it this way: have the dev server approve the plugins and then push them to the test and prod server.

Thank you!